# Non linear regression by levels of several groups in R

Tags: r, regression, nls

Take the example of mtcars in R: I want to make a non linear regression  for the relationship between mpg and disp with:

```
nls(data=mtcars, mpg ~ A * disp^2 + B * disp + C, start=list(A=1,B=1,C=1))
```

But, I need to analyse the relationship for every combination of cyl, gear and carb.

I tried to do this :

```
 nlsList(data=mtcars, mpg ~ A * disp^2 + B * disp + C | cyl * gear * carb, 
                                              start=list(A=1,B=1,C=1))
```

but I have always errors. The final objective is to plot datas with regression with facets of cyl, gear and carb. Could you help me?

Comment: 1 of the facet will be the data with regression for subset(cyl==6 & gear==4 & carb==4). Another facet will be data and regression for  subset(cyl==4 & gear==4 & carb==4) etc.

Comment: Why nls? your regression is linear in the coefficients

Comment: I would drop the nls and do linear with I(disp^2)

Comment: Also as for running the regression for each level, `with(mtcars, table(interaction(cyl, gear, carb, drop=TRUE)))` would suggest there are not enough points to estimate every grouping. [but choosing groups with enough data, this should work `mtcars$f = with(mtcars, interaction(am,vs)) ;
 nlsList(data=mtcars, mpg ~ A * disp^2 + B * disp + C | f,  start=list(A=1,B=1,C=1))` ]

Comment: That's a bad choice of polynomial given the relationship of the variables you're considering.